# How to send multiple emails in a loop with attachments using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Hello, can anyone help me out to write a code which helps me to send multiple emails with attachments in loops at once?**

Now I am explaining what I exactly want to achieve.

This is my table available in excel sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHhdL.png)

Step 01 - I have multiple excel report saved in folder with the same name as the ***Emp Number*** as mentioned in above table.

Step 02 - so I want want code such as it will pick the report from folder by matching report name with the Emp Number mentioned in table and send mail to Email id which is available against those Emp Number

**note:** report name and Emp Number both is same.

It is possible because right now ***I am sending more than 3210+ emails manually***, which is exhausting me.

Comment: Your tasks consists of several subtasks which I suggest to tackle individually: 1) read data from Excel spreadsheet (e.g. [using `pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)). 2) send e-mails via python (e.g. with the  built-in [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) or [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) modules)

Comment: Mr. Albert, You are right. I am having a problem in the 2nd step. I am not aware of this, so can you help me out?

Comment: @beginner_Coder, from which email provider do you want to send your emails ? gmail, outlook or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you have a @gmail address, you can run the code below to send multiple emails with different ExcelFiles attachements (stored in one single folder) to different recipients (including non-gmail addresses).

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

df = pd.read_excel(r'path\\to\\your\\emails_Excelfile.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    emp_number = row['EMP Number']
    email_id = row['Email ID']
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Report number ' + str(emp_number)
    msg['From'] = 'put_your_@gmail_here'
    msg['To'] = email_id
    msg.set_content("Put your message here")
    
    with open(fr"path\\to\\reportsFolder\{emp_number}.xlsx", 'rb') as f:
        file_data=f.read()
        file_name=f.name
        msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='xlsx', filename=file_name)
    
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as server:
            server.login('put_your_@gmail_here', 'put_your_AppPassword_here')
            server.send_message(msg)
    except:
        pass
```

###### `>>> Result`

[image]

##### VERY IMPORTANT :

Since the "Access for the less secure app" in Gmail has been deactivated by Google, you have to generate an APP password so [**`smtplib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) can login your gmail. And to do this, you need to :

1. Open up [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/) (after your sign-in)
2. Under the `"Signing in to Google"` section, activate the `"2-Step Verification"`
3. Create an app password (to get a sixteen string characters)

[image]

Comment: My brother is working wonders for me Thank you so much for your assistance. One last issue I'm having is that if no email address is available for any specific employee number, the loop breaks and throws an exception. what shoul I do for this

Comment: this exception SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'nan': (553, b'5.1.3 The recipient address <nan> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. Learn\n5.1.3 more at\n5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 21-20020a170902c11500b001635b86a790sm3725066pli.44 - gsmtp')}

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the case when an `Email ID` is not available or has a invalid format, you can handle that by adding a `try.. except` statement right before sending the email.. I updated the answer/code. Check it out !

Comment: Thank you so much brother ....... You solved my big problem.......... Thank you

Comment: abokey Can you help me out to write code for same problem but using OUtlook.

Kindlly PFB link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73731813/how-to-send-multiple-emails-in-a-loop-with-attachments-with-the-help-of-outlook

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the usage of `Outlook` for Windows as application to send emails, and you have some table which you want to send called `dataset`, and a list of emails called `emails`:

Initialize the Outlook application, make sure that you have opened it alrealdy before starting the script:

```
import win32com.client as win32
olApp = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
email_sender = "your.email@xxx.xxx"
```

Creating an email object (empty):

```
mail_item = olApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Supposing you want to send a shared email to everyone in copy you can do:

```
mail_item.To = "; ".join(emails)
```

Otherwise, if you want to email singularly just loop to email or use `multithreading` which is more appropriate/fast rather than `multiprocessing` for this kind of tasks.

```
mail_item.Subject = "An unusual email."
mail_item.BodyFormat = 1
mail_item._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, olNS.Accounts.Item(email_sender)))
```

Then, initialize your body as a string:

```
body = ""
```

Think about a static header which will describe the email and the content of the table and *add* it to the body:

```
body += """<td style="line-height:15px;font-family:Arial;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding-bottom:5px">{}</td></br>""".format("A Random Header.")
```

Again, add to the body the pandas table with the `.to_html()` to parse it correctly as html:

```
body += """<br><pre>{}</br></pre>""".format(dataset.to_html())
```

Give the body to the *mail_item*:

```
mail_item.HTMLBody = "<html><body>{}</html></body>".format(body)
```

Send the email:

```
mail_item.Send()
```